# Get all value of checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to get all the values of checked checkboxes in jQuery?

**HTML**

```html
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3" checked>
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" checked>
```

Comment: WELCOME to stackoverflow. Please provide code and clear questions.

Comment: do you want to get the SUM of the the checked checkboxes?

Comment: Something like `$('.messageCheckbox[checked]').map((index, element) => $(element).val()).get()`?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to get all checkboxes with the `querySelectorAll()`method and then use a loop with a conditional statement to show only the values of the boxes that are checked.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.messageCheckbox');
  for(box of boxes){
    if(box.checked){ console.log(box.value) } 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3" checked>
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" checked>
<button id="btn">Get values</button>
```